# Python/Matplotlib - x tick label formatted into multiple columns?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to take:

```
hello world 12345
```

as an x-tick label (already being displayed vertically) and turn it into this:

```
hello world
12345
```

which is an x-tick label with (rotated) two columns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could format the text using the [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#module-textwrap) module from the standard library:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import textwrap

mu, sigma=100, 15
N=4
x=mu + sigma*np.random.randn(N)
plt.bar(range(N), x,  align='center')
labels=[
    'hello world 12345',
    'another long one',
    'what happened to pithy',
    'yada yada',
    ]
labels=[textwrap.fill(text,15) for text in labels]

plt.xticks(range(N), labels)
plt.show()
```

[image]